# How can we interrupt the main thread

Tags: c++, linux, boost-thread

I am using below simple program to generate a sleep for argument specified on command line.

I can't find the `boost::thread` object that corresponds to the main thread. Using an empt `thread_obj`, the `sleep` is working but boost::thread object is not getting interrupted any time I run program.

So is there any specific reason why I am not getting interrupt for `boost::thread` object?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include<boost/date_time/date.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

boost::thread thread_obj;
boost::thread thread_obj1;

void func(void)
{
        char x;
        cout << "enter y to interrupt" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        if(x == 'y')
        {
                cout << "x = 'y'" << endl;
                thread_obj.interrupt();
                cout << "thread interrupt" << endl;
        }
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
        thread_obj1 = boost::thread(&func);
        boost::system_time const timeout = boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(atoi(argv[1]));
        try
        {
                boost::this_thread::sleep(timeout);
        } catch(boost::thread_interrupted &)
        {
                cout <<"thread interrupted" << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: No idea what you're doing with `thread_obj`: there's no thread attached to it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit boost::Thread_obj is only created to apply sleep... is it possible to do like this...??

Comment: No. On which thread would the sleep be applied? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: on thread_obj object of boost::thread....

Comment: @MaulikPanchal look at your posted code. Where is `thread_obj` associated with *any* actual thread?? You clearly create a thread for `thread_obj1`, but not for `thread_obj`.

Comment: @MaulikPanchal: I think you misunderstand what a `boost::thread` object is. That's the specific reason it's not doing what you want. Perhaps you can clarify which thread you wish to interrupt and from where, and which thread you wish to sleep and from where.

Comment: I want to interrupt thread_obj from "func" function and wanna wish to sleep thread_obj from main...

Comment: @MaulikPanchal I've improved the question wording. I hope I got your question right. If so, this might be an interesting question (it might not be possible, in fact, since I think interruption points rely on quite a bit of Boost Thread specific hidden machinery under the hood)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use interruption points on the main thread (since boost doesn't control it). Iinterruption points rely on quite a bit of Boost Thread specific hidden machinery under the hood.

---

If you want to "apply" sleep on the current thread use `this_thread`.

I'm afraid you cannot interrupt the main thread. However, you *can* just run the main program on a separate thread that you join immediately:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a63da138897ad3ff)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/date.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

boost::thread thread_obj;
boost::thread thread_obj1;

void func(void)
{
    char x;
    cout << "enter y to interrupt" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == 'y') {
        cout << "x = 'y'" << endl;
        thread_obj.interrupt();
        cout << "thread interrupt" << endl;
    }
}

void real_main() {
    boost::system_time const timeout = boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(3);
    try {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(timeout);
    }
    catch (boost::thread_interrupted &) {
        cout << "thread interrupted" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread_obj1 = boost::thread(&func);
    thread_obj = boost::thread(&real_main);
    thread_obj.join();
}
```

Comment: Thnx @sehe... i know this method of creating thread but isn't there any way like without creating seperate thread of sleep we can apply interrupt function directly on created thread_obj...??

Comment: Mmm. I left that part out of the answer :) It was in my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571271/how-can-we-interrupt-the-main-thread/30572147?noredirect=1#comment49214182_30571271. Edited now